# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Cyrillic_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-core

MS SQL server 2017

asp.net core 2

I call store procedure from c#:

```
res = db.Query<SearchPictureInfoOutputModel>("sp_SearchPictureInfo", new { Prc_ID = input.Prc_ID, Cust_ID = input.Cust_ID, AppCode = input.AppCode},
                             commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get error:

**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Cyrillic_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.'**

If i call procedure from ms managment studio

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_SearchPictureInfo]
        @Prc_ID = 2663,
        @Cust_ID = 26429,
        @AppCode = N'19139'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

No error, just return value.

How can I solve collation?

Comment: What's db ? EF or EF Core or ... ? What's the collation on DB ?

Comment: no, we dont use EF. just call store procedure of sql server db.

Comment: Ok but what kind of object is `db` ? Can you show more code ?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your system databases have different collation.

You can check that by executing the following query in your SQL Management studio:

```
SELECT name, collation_name  
FROM sys.databases
```

Also on non master databases you can use right-click -> Properties -> General -> Maintenance and you will see Collation as last option.

Non-master ones can be changed using this query:

```
USE master;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE <<YOUR_DATABASE_OTHER_THAN_MASTER>>
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS ;  
GO
```

If you have to change the master one (like I do) you will not be able via the SQL Management studio. The easiest way for me was to stop it as well as all SQL services, the navigate to the binn folder of the SQL (for 2016 and x64) was this one:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn

Then if you use the default instance just run:

```
sqlservr.exe -m -q"Latin1_General_CI_AS"
```

or whatever collation you want to set. If you have several instances add also the following parameter:

```
-s"<<YOUR_SQL_INSTANCE>>" e.g. -> sqlservr.exe -m -s"SQLEXP2014" -q"Latin1_General_CI_AS"
```

Hopefully this will help you to resolve your problem :)

**Sources:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/view-collation-information?view=sql-server-2017

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3519/changing-sql-server-collation-after-installation/

Comment: Just to add for people like me, who don't understand in details of what happened here:
---
1. You, most likely would have to change your "master", even if your query does not involve master database. Once you change it - all the other databases will change as well.
---
2. The SQL sever could be installed in another directory. For me it was: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn
---
3. After you run sqlservr.exe from command prompt and wait until it updates the setting, you can stop it in command prompt and then restart the service normally